# Why doesn't the pointer object exist after the new allocation in a recursive function?

Tags: c++

I try to implement a simple binary tree in C++.

```cpp
// mytree.h

class MyNode {
public:
  MyNode() : ndata(nullptr), depth(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
  MyNode(uint32_t d)
      : ndata(nullptr), depth(d), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
  ~MyNode() {
    if (left != nullptr)
      delete left;
    if (right != nullptr)
      delete right;
    delete ndata;
    // do not delete node->data
  }
  void print(const MyNode *n, std::string indent) {
    if (n != nullptr) {
      printf("%sNode:\n", indent.c_str());
    }
  }
  // A n-dim data value
  float *ndata;
  // depth of the node in the tree
  uint32_t depth;
  // Left child node
  MyNode *left;
  // Right child node
  MyNode *right;
};

class MyTree {
public:
  MyTree() : root_(nullptr), depth_(0) {}
  ~MyTree() {
    if (root_) {
      delete root_->left;
      delete root_->right;
    }
  }
  void insert_node(MyNode *node, float *data);
  void print();
  MyNode *root_;
  uint32_t depth_;
};

//mytree.cpp
void MyTree::insert_node(MyNode *node, float *data) {
  if (node == nullptr) {
    std::printf("Create new node %f\n", *data);
    node = new MyNode(depth_);
    node->left = nullptr;
    node->right = nullptr;
  } else {
    depth_++;
    std::printf("Go next\n");
    insert_node(node->left, data);
    insert_node(node->right, data);
  }
}

void MyTree::print() {
  if (root_) {
    std::printf("Printing tree\n");
    root_->print(root_, "");
  }
}
```

If I create an object in my main.cpp, the insert function always detects that the root is `nullptr`.

```cpp
int main() {
  MyTree mc;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    float *data = new float();
    *data = i;
    mc.insert_node(mc.root_, data);
  }
  mc.print();
}
```

Running the code it return this outputs:

```
Create new node 0.000000
Create new node 1.000000
Create new node 2.000000
Create new node 3.000000
Create new node 4.000000
```

Somehow, I cannot find my programming failure here. Why does the created node object for the variable `root_` always vanish. Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: `node = new MyNode(depth_)`  here `node` is local to `MyTree::insert_node` and hence `mc.root_` is not updated and creates a memory leak. Either return the allocated node or pass `MyNode **node` as an argument to the function

Comment: Side note: you have a potential ownership problem here. The preceding node in the three takes ownership of the node, but what if someone passes in a pointer to a node that is already owned?

Comment: Passing a node that is already in the tree into a tree method seems weird. why should the caller have to know about the tree's head node? What's to stop them from `delete`ing it, setting it to null, or pointing it somewhere utterly stupid by mistake and leaving the tree in an inconsistent state?

Comment: I'm figuring out what you are doing here, but I dislike it. Say the program calls `insert_node` on tree X with and provides a node from tree Y? `void MyTree::insert_node(MyNode *node, float *data)` should be made `private`, changed to `void MyTree::insert_node(MyNode *&node, float *data)` to allow updating the `node` argument, and be called by a `public` `void MyTree::insert_node(float *data)` that eliminates all need for visibility into the tree's data.

Comment: try using `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`. They exist for a reason. The answer to your question, however, lines in `insert_node`. I don't think you quite grasp how pointers work yet. You aren't doing in that function what you think you're doing in that function.

Comment: @TruthSeeker, thanks! The missing * was the cause.

Comment: @user4581301, passing a node from an existing tree is not the use case.

Comment: That's the thing about bugs. They're never part of the intended use-case. Make it impossible and you've eliminated a possible bug.

Comment: Code flow has some major flaws, `Tree` must have a `node` and just a row data must be pushed/inserted to tree rather `node` itself.  `Node` is a internal representation of `tree` and `client` need not to be aware of node representaion. Good practice would be `class MyTree { class MyNode{}; void insert(float);};`  refer:[std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) API's